# Firebase resulut : Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: java, firebase

Given the following code :

```
String MESSAGING_SCOPE1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";

String[] SCOPES = { MESSAGING_SCOPE1 };

GoogleCredentials googleCredentials;
try {
    googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("D:/FCM_ProjectKey/TEST/ test.json"));
    googleCredentials = googleCredentials.createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
    
    googleCredentials.refreshAccessToken();
   return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e);
}
return "";
```

Unable to send message to Firebase:

```
{  "error": {    
"code": 401,    
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",    
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",   
"details": [      {        
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",        
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",        
"domain": "googleapis.com",       
 "metadata": {          
 "service": "fcm.googleapis.com",          
 "method": "google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmService.SendMessage"        }      }    ]  }}
```

I can't find the answer on how to solve it.